# How can I add www in my domain sitecore? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, sitecore8

If I search on google, my domain look like this : `xxxxxxxxxx.com`. I want it to look `www.xxxxxxxxxx.com`

And if clicked it will go to `https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/`. I want it to go to `https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/`

How can I do it? Do I just need to change in web.config?

My web.config like this :

[image]

Is it true that I custom `<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" redirectType="Permanent" />`  to `<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/" redirectType="Permanent" />` ? Right?

Comment: Typically, you'd assign a DNS name for "www.mydomain.com" to point to the server.  All the URL rewrites in the world won't help you before you have DNS successfully resolving your hostname.

Comment: @FoggyDay I try to added a custom domain in portal azure and click validate and it appears that way. Next I was confused to set up. Do I need to run next? https://ibb.co/c18s2xh